# What is the XDocument equivalent of XMLDocument.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI

Tags: linq-to-xml

I am trying to use XDocument for its linq methods.

I have seen `doc.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix( "i" )` where doc is the XDocument and "i" is the namespace, but, with XmlDocument, I don't have to know about "i".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`XElement.GetDefaultNamespace Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.getdefaultnamespace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)